# What's the closest we can come to a definitive list of concepts and guiding principles in OO Software Design?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm hoping to assemble a definitive and useful study guide. Please help!

I'll start:

- Program to an Interface not an Implementation
- Interface Separation Principle
- DRY Principle (Don't Repeat Yourself)
- Law of Demeter
- Liskov Substitution Principle
- Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control
- Separation of Concerns
- Loose Coupling
- Open Closed Principle
- Prefer Composition over Inheritance

Comment: though this is a great topic, it isn't quite a question with a definitive, acceptable answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that preferring composition over inheritance is actually a principle... it's more like knowing when to use which. You can accomplish almost anything with composition that you can accomplish with inheritance, but it isn't always a good idea to do so.

Comment: is there a principle that tells you when it's good to use one over the other?  Plus, in my mind, I think interface inheritance + delegating is still composition.

Comment: Doesn't "prefer composition over inheritance" say that OO is a failure, if we agree that inheritance is one of the hallmarks of OO?  Abstract data types and encapsulation might be enough.

Comment: @duffymo, haha we already knew that, yet we still have to cater to the standards set before us. At least I do, b/c I'm just starting out :-).  But actually I first saw that in the gang of four book.  All this dependency injection stuff that's popular lately is basically making OOP approximate Functional programming, which makes it more useful.

Comment: I don't think there is a real principle that tells you when to inherit and when to compose. Or for that matter, when to use mix-ins in languages that support them. "Good" object-oriented design is hard to define because 'object-oriented programming' is difficult to define.

Comment: If the question is 'let us do this', is the correct answer not 'no'?

Comment: If you think a question should be made community wiki for any other reason than to allow more users to edit the "community-owned" posts, then what you really want is to close the question. @frustrated

Comment: any suggestions as to how I can change this outcome?  it seems like a useful thing to be asking, and some folks seem to agree, though maybe I haven't found the magic incantation that will satisfy everyone? I'm very interested in the answer, and though the question's actually impossible to answer, the form of the answer requested is very specific and useful, right?  I know others could use this, too.

Answer (score 7):

I'd just refer people to [Uncle Bob Martin's writings](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/publishedArticles.html) and call it a day.  I think context beats a simple list any day.  There's lots to read there.

Know the rules; know when the rules don't apply; know when to break the rules.

Most of all, don't base all your knowledge on dogmatic lists of snippets.

Comment: One problem I've found when learning OO design is trying to wade through the myriad of different approaches available. Starting out and getting a good grasp of what is relevant and suitable takes a bloody long time (for some of us).

Comment: I think learning anything well takes a long time: http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: yea, I'm just wanting a starting point for further study really, to make sure I don't miss anything.

Answer (score 2):

My definitive list:

1. Find, read, and understand the original "Law of Demeter" papers.
2. Find an Object Friendly language that you like.
3. Determine the following: Given the intention of maintaining encapsulation, maintainability, parsimony and readability, and given the features of this language, how should I use this language?

3 is kind of a doozy, but at least you'll have a point of view from which to read other people's advice on how to use the language.

Answer (score 2):

- Program mindfully
- Immutability is your friend
- So are state transition diagrams
- O/R frameworks are not all they are cracked up to be
- Program mindfully
- Patterns are a communication mechanism, not a mandate

Comment: +1 just for "O/R frameworks are not all they are cracked up to be".  I like all of these a lot.

Comment: what's the value of state transition diagrams?

Comment: In my experience, if there's no non-trivial state transition diagram for a class, there are good odds the objects are really just a bit of data. (Note the states might well be private to the class).

Answer (score 1):

Program to an Interface not an Implementation.

Comment: Unless an interface is overkill.

Comment: Closely followed by understanding what that actually means.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Separation Principle

DRY Principle (Don't Repeat Yourself)

Comment: Maybe not, but it still applies.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Pretty well everything in the original list also applies to hardware, let alone any software paradigm. The mains plug is LSP in practice.

Answer (score 0):

General Responsibility Assignment Software Patterns (or Principles)